Two dimensional Lorentz group
The Lorentz group $O(D-1,1)$ in $D$ dimensions is the group of linear transformations $\mathbb{R}^D \to \mathbb{R}^D$ that preserves the Minkowski metric $(\cdot ,\cdot ):\mathbb{R}^D\times \mathbb{R}^D\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(\alpha ,\beta)=\eta_{ij}\alpha^i\beta^i$ where $\eta_{11}=-1$, $\eta_{ii}=1$ for $2\leq i\leq D$ and $\eta_{ij}=0$ otherwise. If consists of matrices $f$ such that $f^T\eta f=\eta$. The connected Lorentz group $SO^{\uparrow}(D-1,1)$ is the subgroup of $O(D-1,1)$ consists of those $f$ with $\det (f)=1$ and $f_{11}>0$. My question is that is $SO^{\uparrow}(1,1)$ isomorphic to a well-known group?

It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. An isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to SO^{\uparrow}(1,1)$ is given by
$$t\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh t&\sinh t\\
\sinh t&\cosh t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To check this you can verify that the Lie algebra of $SO^{\uparrow}(1,1)$ is 1-dimensional and spanned by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In this case, the isomorphism I mentioned is given by the exponential map.

Thank you so much for your help.
